# Maximize size of every page when combining pdfs in Pyton

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to combine different PDFs. The problem is that some are in landscape and some in portrait, and also, some are bigger than others. When I combine them naively using PyPDF2, some pages become very small.

How can I resize all the pages, such that either the width or height is maximal, and the other is as big as the aspect ratio allows? This is my current code:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

i = []

for f in sorted(os.listdir())):
    i.append(open(os.path.join("slides", f), "rb"))

w = PdfWriter()

for chap, r in enumerate(map(PdfReader, i)):
    for n in range(r.getNumPages()):
        w.addPage(r.getPage(n))

w.write(open("out.pdf", "wb"))
```

Comment: create a list of file-object is not a good idea... you open the descriptors but you close them? just pass the paths to `PdfReader`, smt like `map(PdfReader, paths)` where paths is a list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to first find the maximum width and height, and then scaling the pages to have the same size as either the width or the height, according to if it is bigger than or smaller than the aspect ratio of the max height and width. Note that the following code assumes that all pages start at `x,y=0`

```py
max_w, max_h = 0, 0
for pdf_reader in map(PdfReader, in_streams):
    for page in pdf_reader.pages:
        _, _, w, h = page.mediaBox

        max_w = max(w, max_w)
        max_h = max(h, max_h)

page_idx = 0
for chapter_name, pdf_reader in zip(chapter_names, map(PdfReader, in_streams)):
    print(chapter_name)
    for page in pdf_reader.pages:
        _, _, w, h = page.mediaBox

        scale = 0
        if w / h > max_w / max_h:  # expand horizontal
            scale = max_w / w
        else:  # expand vertical
            scale = max_h / h

        page.scaleBy(float(scale))

        pdf_writer.addPage(page)
```